# How to post values and get response in PHP

Tags: php, curl, post

I want to do e-mail verification using [email-checker](https://email-checker.net/). I want to post `email` and `id`, and I would like to withdraw it from the posted page, whichever answer is BAD or SUCCESS. Posted page is `https://email-checker.net/check`.

**Here is my code:**

```
$curl_connection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.bulkemailchecker.com/free-email-checker/');
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
$data=curl_exec($curl_connection);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just a note on that service. I just tested with four different addresses on my domain (I have a catch all address so what ever you write, I'll get the emails). It told me that two of them was "Unknown" and two was valid. I wouldn't trust it. If you want to verify an email, just send a confirmation email.

Comment: You haven't posted any parsing code, just calls that set options and execute `curl`. Please have a look at [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The URL in your code is not the same as the URL you mention in your text.

Answer (score 0):

first make a GET request to the url, in the headers you will receive a cookie session id, and in the html you will receive a [CSRF token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Cookie-to-header_token) called `_csrf`, save both, and make a new request to `https://email-checker.net/check` with both the cookie session and the csrf token, and the email, in the parameter (aptly) named `email`, using a HTTP POST request, with the `application/x-www-urlencoded` encoding. now your answer will be in the text content of the element in the html you receive with the id `results-wrapper`.

example implementation using [hhb_curl](https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php#L407):

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
const EMAIL = 'webmaster@hotmail.com';
require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
$hc = new hhb_curl ( '', true );
$html = $hc->exec ( 'https://email-checker.net' )->getStdOut ();
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$xp = new DOMXPath ( $domd );
$csrf_token = $xp->query ( '//input[@name="_csrf"]' )->item ( 0 )->getAttribute ( "value" );
$html = $hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://email-checker.net/check',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( array (
                '_csrf' => $csrf_token,
                'email' => EMAIL 
        ) ) 
) )->exec ()->getStdOut ();
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$xp = new DOMXPath ( $domd );
$result = trim ( $xp->query ( '//*[@id="results-wrapper"]' )->item ( 0 )->textContent );
var_dump ( $result );
```

currently outputs: `string(30) "OK The email address is valid."` - meaning that `webmaster@hotmail.com` is valid. (see line 3)

- warning, after 5 attempts in less than an hour, you'll get the output `Limit Exceeded Only 5 lookups per hour is allowed.  Try Premium Plan` instead
- warning, the results seem highly unreliable. if you actually need to validate an email address for something, send a verification url to the email instead.

Comment: Thanks for help. But I have a problem. 
I have tried your code but it gives me the error every time (SMTP server timeout). And when I enter an email like asdasd@asdasd.com it returns OK.

Comment: @MehmetAcar yeah, that seems to be a bug in their checker though. ask `admin@email-checker.net` about the unreliable results.